# Unable to generate a public url with Gradio on python

Tags: python, gradio

I've programmed a python script using gradio. But I can't generate a public URL. When I run the program, my terminal returns the following:

```
Could not create share link. Missing file: /home/gabriel/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gradio/frpc_linux_aarch64_v0.2. 

Please check your internet connection. This can happen if your antivirus software blocks the download of this file. You can install manually by following these steps: 

1. Download this file: https://cdn-media.huggingface.co/frpc-gradio-0.2/frpc_linux_aarch64
2. Rename the downloaded file to: frpc_linux_aarch64_v0.2
3. Move the file to this location: /home/gabriel/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gradio
```

The problem is that when I try to download the missing file I get a 403 error. It probably doesn't exist anymore.

```
gabriel@raspberrypi ~> wget https://cdn-media.huggingface.co/frpc-gradio-0.2/frpc_linux_aarch64
--2023-08-25 21:42:22--  https://cdn-media.huggingface.co/frpc-gradio-0.2/frpc_linux_aarch64
Résolution de cdn-media.huggingface.co (cdn-media.huggingface.co)… 2600:9000:2450:7e00:19:6fb8:2ac0:93a1, 2600:9000:2450:9e00:19:6fb8:2ac0:93a1, 2600:9000:2450:8400:19:6fb8:2ac0:93a1, ...
Connexion à cdn-media.huggingface.co (cdn-media.huggingface.co)|2600:9000:2450:7e00:19:6fb8:2ac0:93a1|:443… connecté.
requête HTTP transmise, en attente de la réponse… 403 Forbidden
2023-08-25 21:42:22 erreur 403 : Forbidden.
```

Comment: No solution yet, but there is an open issue in-case easier to track --> https://github.com/gradio-app/gradio/issues/6053